# Cannot install packages in Lubuntu 12.04

Tags: apt, updates, lubuntu, chromium, repository

I've just installed `lubuntu 12.04` on an Acer aspire one netbook. I've noticed that although `chromium-browser` is installed, it doesn't come with a `flash-player`. I tried to install it using

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

but I get the error

```
E: Unable to locate package flashplugin-installer
```

I also tried to install some other basic packages like `gedit`, `deluge`, `kate`, `geany` but I get the same error. Then I tried to update all repositories using

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but while it's running there are some errors like

```
Err http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Sources
404  Not Found
```

or

`W: Failed to fetch     http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found`

Why is this happening? I've checked my internet connection and it's fine. I also tried to install `chrome` using GDebi package installer` but I get an error

```
Dependency is not satisfiable : libnns3(>=3.14.3)
```

I believe that somehow I cannot see the repositories. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that as of April, Quantal (12.10) has reached end of life and is no longer supported in the main Ubuntu package repositories. However I don't know why it's trying to install a Quantal package on a Precise system. This might be of use but I'd want to check first that your precise sources aren't touched by sed (sorry, sed's not my area):

[How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your configuration files with `sudo apt-get -o dpkg::options::="--force-confnew" -o dpkg::options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install PAKET`

If this does not help, open your sources.list file with `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and try commenting this part out `http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/restricted/source/Sources` using a "#" in front of the line.

After changing your sources.list file, save it update your sources.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your first suggestion `sudo apt-get -o dpkg::options::="--force-confnew" -o dpkg::options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install PAKET` gives the same error. I replaced *PAKET* with `deluge`, `gedit`, `kate` but again the same. Also in the `sources.list` there weren't any `gr.archives` at all...